# Paypal form with special characters

Tags: php, forms, paypal, parameters

I'm sending a post form to paypal with custom text parameters.
I checked my vars before send the form and the special characters are ok.

But in the paypal page (register option) the text appears ("Ocón") encoded in utf8("OcÃ³n").

I tried to decoded it before send, but only was worst ("Ocï¿½n")

Any idea?

Comment: I removed *Solved* in the title, and the answer at the end of the text. On this website it's better to accept an answer in order to mark a question as *solved*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I added accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" in the form and solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use [iconv](https://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php):

```
echo iconv( 'UTF-8' , 'ISO-8859-1' , 'OcÃ³n');
```

adjusting encodings to your website. It worked fine for me.

Comment: This not worked for me.
But you gave me an idea, finally I added accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" to the form.